# get user role from database based on user id in angular

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angular5

I am using an "auth service" to keep all the user authentication functions. When the user is authenticated, I get the user's id and I fetch the relevant record from the database table, but I fail to get the value of the "role" field. The code I am using in the constructor is this:

```
constructor(
    private _firebaseAuth: AngularFireAuth,
    private db: AngularFireDatabase,
    private router: Router) {
    this.user = _firebaseAuth.authState;

    this.user.subscribe(
        (user) => {
            if (user) {
                this.userDetails = user;

                this.userEmail = this.userDetails.email;
                this.uid = this.userDetails.uid;

                this.getUserRole(this.uid).subscribe(result => {
                    this.role = result.role;
                    console.log('role >>>>>>>>>>>>>', this.role);
                });

                console.log('uid >>>>>>>>>>>>>', this.uid);
                console.log('role >>>>>>>>>>>>>', this.role);
            }
            else {
                this.userDetails = null;
            }
        }
    );
}

getUserRole(userId: string): Observable<any> {
    return this.db.list('users', ref => ref.orderByChild('uid').equalTo(this.uid)).valueChanges()
        .map(result => result[0]);
}
```

`this.uid` has the correct value, but `this.role` is undefined.

I suppose the problem that the call to the database table is asynchronous.
How can i get this value?

Comment: Did you try `this.currUser.subscribe(val => this.role = val[0].role)` ?

Comment: Same result... `this.role` is undefined outside `subscribe`

Comment: You should wait for the subscribe to complete or else you will always get it undefined.

Comment: Like this?         `this.user.subscribe(
            val => this.role = val[0].role,
            () => 
        );` What should follow '()=>' ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have added some code to make you understand the callbacks of observable. Have a look at it.

```
this.currUser.subscribe(
        (val) => {
            // This is called as success callback
            this.role = val[0].role;
           // perform task using this.role. You should be writing your code here.
        },
        (error) => {
                // This is called as error callback, It will be executed if any erorrs were thrown from `currUser()`
                // log if there are any errors here
        },
        () => {
            // This is called as complete block
            // This will be executed after success callback or the error callback.
        }
);
```

UPDATE :

```
this.user.subscribe(
    (user) => {
        if (user) {
            this.userDetails = user;

            this.userEmail = this.userDetails.email;
            this.uid = this.userDetails.uid;

            this.getUserRole(this.uid).subscribe(result => {
                this.role = result.role;
                console.log('role >>>>>>>>>>>>>', this.role);       // print log 1
            });

            // log 2 will be executed before log 1 this is due to asynchronous behaviour
            console.log('role >>>>>>>>>>>>>', this.role);           // print log 2
        }
        else {
            this.userDetails = null;
        }
    }
);
```

log 2 will be executed before log 1 this is due to asynchronous behaviour. If you are thinking that your code executes sequentially with line numbers, then you are wrong. `getUserRole` is asynchronous method.

You can access `this.role` from other components as well using `get` or `set`. Whatever you have done is appropriate.

What you should be doing is fetch `this.role` only if it is not undefined.

In your external component where your are trying to access `this.role`, check for `undefined` first and then access it.

some-other component .ts

```
if(this.role != undefined){
 let role = this.role
}
```

DEMO : 
Check [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jampsh?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.ts) to see how asynchronous methods work

Comment: I understood how the structure should be, but I don't understand what should be done in the `() =>`. Outside `(val) =>` variable `this.role` is still undefined

Comment: You cannot use `this.role` until success block is executed. It is an asynchronous operation. Your `console.log(this.role)` outside subscribe block will be executed before your success block gets executed. That is why you get undefined.

Comment: I understand why I get undefined in `console.log`. If I put the  `console.log` in `() =>` nothing happens. This means that `subscribe` is never completed? Is there any other way to get the value?

Comment: In your code you say `console.log(this.role)` inside success block works, now you are saying nothing happens.

Comment: The `console.log(this.role)` was outside the success block. I put in the success block after following your example and at that point nothing happened

Comment: What does `val[0]` print inside success callback?

Comment: `val[0]` inside success callback prints the object which contains the user's data (name, last name, email, role). `var[0].role` prints the user's role. How can I use the value of `var[0].role outside `'subscribe'? This the code `this.currUser.subscribe(
            (val) => {
                this.role = val[0].role;
            },
            (error) => {
                console.log('Error');
            },
            () => {
                console.log('this.role:', this.role); // not executed
            }
        );`

Comment: Please add your entire code, where you are trying to access `this.role` or create a plunker for the same.

Comment: I modified the code to use a function: `getUserRole(userId: string): Observable<any> {
        return this.db.list('users', ref => ref.orderByChild('uid').equalTo(this.uid)).valueChanges()
            .map(result => result[0]);
    }` and this is the function call in the constructor `this.getUserRole(this.uid).subscribe(result => {
                        this.role = result;
                    });` I am trying to access `this.role` after the function call

Comment: Show the full code, where you are trying to access `this.role` along with the above code. Add this code to your question. So that I can suggest to rearrange your code.

Comment: I updated the code in the question. The `console.log('role >>>>>>>>>>>>>', this.role);` prints a value. The second `console.log('role >>>>>>>>>>>>>', this.role);` returns undefined. I want to read the `role` from another component using `get` `set` of store it in local storage

Comment: I have added some more description. Hope you will get that.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. This asynchronous execution causes the variable not to be undefined or have the wrong value when I read it from the component. The component from which I try to read the value is a sidebar which contains the navigation menu and the variable gets the correct value only when I click a menu item

Comment: I have added the working demo for asynchronous functions. You can have a look at that. And if your issue is resolved, mark the answer and close it.

Comment: Thank you for your answers, I used the code you posted but still I don't have the results I need. I think will look for another workaround

Comment: Finally I got it work by calling the function that will get the user role in onNgInit() and use the variable in the html template. I added the code in the answer.

Comment: Nice that your problem is solved. Well if you had checked the demo link that I have added, It utilizes ngOnInit() as opposed to constructor. It is always a good practice to write starter code in ngOnInit().

Comment: I am a beginner in angular and I realized that after the issue I faced. Thanks again for your help

Answer (score 0):

You cannot access the variable outside .subscribe() method, place it within the subscribe

```
 this.currUser.subscribe(val => {
    this.role = val[0].role;
    console.log(this.role);
});
```

Comment: If I place it within the subscribe, how can I use it?

Comment: call a method and use it inside

Comment: Should this get this.currUser as and argument and return something?

Comment: no just call whaterver method newMethod(this.role);

Comment: `this.role` is not visible out of the function. The problem is that `this.role` is not visible out of subscribe

Answer (score 0):

I created the following function in the user service:

```
getUserRole(userId: string): Observable<any> {
    return this.db.list('users', ref => ref.orderByChild('uid').equalTo(userId)).valueChanges()
        .map(result => result[0]);
}
```

then I got the user id in the component:

```
get uid(): string {
    return this.authService.uid;
}
set uid(value: string) {
    this.authService.uid = value;
}
```

and called the function in onNgInit():

```
ngOnInit() {
    if (this.uid != undefined) {
        let uid = this.uid;

        this.userService.getUserRole(this.uid).subscribe(result => {
                    this.role = result.role;
        });
    }
}
```

Finally I used `*ngIf="role == '<role>'` in the html template